# Datastore which is equivalent of which is equivalent of SQL execute( "update table set colum=%d where column2='%s'" % (value1,value2))?

Tags: python, sql, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm trying to modify the code of naive bayes classifier provided by the excellent book Programming Collective Intelligence, adapting it to the GAE datastore (the provided code uses pysqlite2). But trying to do it, I'm encountering in this line:

```
       update.put()
```

from this block:

```
def incf(self,f,cat):
    count=self.fcount(f,cat)
    if count==0:
      fc_value = fc(feature = f, category = cat, count = 1)
      fc_value.put()
    else:
        update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM fc where feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
   #     if update:
        update.count = count + 1
        update.put()
  #      else:
#      self.con.execute(
 #       "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
  #      % (count+1,f,cat))
```

This error:

```
File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 151, in train
    self.incf(f,cat)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 88, in incf
    update.put()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 1074, in put
    return datastore.Put(self._entity, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 579, in Put
    return PutAsync(entities, **kwargs).get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\datastore.py", line 529, in PutAsync
    'Cannot put a partial entity: %s' % entity)
BadRequestError: Cannot put a partial entity: {u'count': 2L, 'category': None, 'feature': None}
```

What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of this SQL:

```
self.con.execute(
    "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
    % (count+1,f,cat))
```

How can I do this?

Here the entire code:

```
import os

import random

import re

import math

from google.appengine.ext import db

import webapp2

import jinja2

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class fc(db.Model):
    feature = db.StringProperty()
    category = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()

fc_class = fc()

class cc(db.Model):
    category = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()

cc_class = cc()

def getfeatures(doc):
  splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
  # Split the words by non-alpha characters
  words=[s.lower() for s in splitter.split(doc)
          if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]
  return dict([(w,1) for w in words])

class classifier:
  def __init__(self,getfeatures, filename=None):
    # Counts of feature/category combinations
    self.fc={}
    # Counts of documents in each category
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures

#  def setdb(self,dbfile):
#    self.con=sqlite.connect('db_file')
#    self.con=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
#    self.con.execute('create table if not exists fc(feature,category,count)')
#    self.con.execute('create table if not exists cc(category,count)')

  def incf(self,f,cat):
    count=self.fcount(f,cat)
    if count==0:
      fc_value = fc(feature = f, category = cat, count = 1)
      fc_value.put()
    else:
        update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM fc where feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
   #     if update:
        update.count = count + 1
        update.put()
  #      else:
#      self.con.execute(
 #       "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
  #      % (count+1,f,cat))

  def fcount(self,f,cat):
    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM fc WHERE feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
#    res=self.con.execute(
#      'select count from fc where feature="%s" and category="%s"'
#      %(f,cat)).fetchone()
    if res is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return res.count
#        return float(res[0])

  def incc(self,cat):
    count=self.catcount(cat)
    if count==0:
      #  self.con.execute("insert into cc values ('%s',1)" % (cat))
      cc_value = cc(category = cat, count = 1)
      cc_value.put()
    else:
        update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM cc where category =:category", category = cat).get()
        update.count = count + 1
        update.put()
#      self.con.execute("update cc set count=%d where category='%s'"
#                       % (count+1,cat))

  def catcount(self,cat):
#    res=self.con.execute('select count from cc where category="%s"'
 #                        %(cat)).fetchone()
    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM cc WHERE category =:category", category = cat).get()
    if res is None: return 0
#    else: return float(res[0])
    else: return float(res)

  def categories(self):
#    cur = self.con.execute('select category from cc');
    cur = db.GqlQuery("SELECT category FROM cc").fetch(999)
    return [d[0] for d in cur]

  def totalcount(self):
   # res=self.con.execute('select sum(count) from cc').fetchone();
    all_cc = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM cc").fetch(999)
    res = 0
    for cc in all_cc:
        count = cc.count
        res+=count
#    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT sum(count) FROM cc").get()
#    if res==None: return 0
    if res == 0: return 0
#    return res[0]
    return res

  def train(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Increment the count for every feature with this category
    for f in features.keys():
##    for f in features:
      self.incf(f,cat)
    # Increment the count for this category
    self.incc(cat)
#    self.con.commit()

  def fprob(self,f,cat):
    if self.catcount(cat)==0: return 0
    # The total number of times this feature appeared in this
    # category divided by the total number of items in this category
    return self.fcount(f,cat)/self.catcount(cat)

  def weightedprob(self,f,cat,prf,weight=1.0,ap=0.5):
    # Calculate current probability
    basicprob=prf(f,cat)
    # Count the number of times this feature has appeared in
    # all categories
    totals=sum([self.fcount(f,c) for c in self.categories()])

    # Calculate the weighted average
    bp=((weight*ap)+(totals*basicprob))/(weight+totals)
    return bp

class naivebayes(classifier):
  def __init__(self,getfeatures):
    classifier.__init__(self, getfeatures)
    self.thresholds={}

  def docprob(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Multiply the probabilities of all the features together
    p=1
    for f in features: p*=self.weightedprob(f,cat,self.fprob)
    return p

  def prob(self,item,cat):
    catprob=self.catcount(cat)/self.totalcount()
    docprob=self.docprob(item,cat)
    return docprob*catprob

  def setthreshold(self,cat,t):
    self.thresholds[cat]=t

  def getthreshold(self,cat):
    if cat not in self.thresholds: return 1.0
    return self.thresholds[cat]

  def classify(self,item,default=None):
    probs={}
    # Find the category with the highest probability
    max=0.0
    for cat in self.categories():
      probs[cat]=self.prob(item,cat)
      if probs[cat]>max:
        max=probs[cat]
        best=cat
    # Make sure the probability exceeds threshold*next best
    for cat in probs:
      if cat==best: continue
      if probs[cat]*self.getthreshold(best)>probs[best]: return default
    return best

def sampletrain(cl):
  cl.train('Nobody owns the water.','good')
  cl.train('the quick rabbit jumps fences','good')
  cl.train('buy pharmaceuticals now','bad')
  cl.train('make quick money at the online casino','bad')
  cl.train('the quick brown fox jumps','good')


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {"given_sentence":'put a name here'}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
        nb = naivebayes(getfeatures)
        sampletrain(nb)
        given_sentence = self.request.get("given_sentence")
        spam_result = nb.classify(given_sentence)
        submit_button = self.request.get("submit_button")
        if submit_button:
            self.redirect('/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))

class test_resultHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        spam_result = self.request.get("spam_result")
        given_sentence = self.request.get("given_sentence")
        test_result_values = {"spam_result": spam_result,
                             "given_sentence": given_sentence}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('test_result.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(test_result_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/test_result', test_resultHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: Do you have some indentation errors in your first block of code?

Comment: No, indentation in my code is OK. It was a paste error that I fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that GQL construction ("SELECT count FROM fc ..."), you're doing a [projection query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Projection).  The entities returned by a projection query are only partially populated, so they cannot be saved back to the Datastore.
You can instead fetch the full entities (e.g. using GQL, "SELECT * FROM fc..."), which will allow a put() to the datastore.